# Bevel and Subsurface

Tags: modeling, bevel, smooth

I created a object, when I bevelled it with 0.01 amount and added a Subdivision modifier. It leaves a sharp edge. How can I solve it. Please help me solving it.

[image]

i am actually trying to do like this

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You probably just need to increase the limit angle.

If the limit angle is smaller than the angle those two faces are making then the edge between them will get beveled too. And now, since more geometry has been introduced in on that edge, after subdivision, you will get that sharp edge like situation.

Here I have demonstrated what I am trying to explain with the wireframe:

Angle Limit: 0 deg
[image]
After subdivision:
[image]

Angle Limit: 30 deg
[image]
After subdivision:
[image]

Comment: I edited the question...  Please check the wireframe of the mesh

Comment: I already said this in my question "And now, since more geometry has been introduced on that edge, after subdivision, you will get that sharp edge like situation." This is simply because the newly introduced vertices will get clumped up in that region. A face becomes 4 faces. Now look at the faces you have got. There will be 4 faces inside each of thoses faces. There is probably no way (f you want to keep the bevel the way you have right now) other than manually adjusting the mesh after applying the bevel and then sputting on a subdivision modifier.